# Finding HTTP methods from an API

Tags: http, http-proxy

Is there a way to find the different HTTP methods from an API URL? For example, `api.apithing.com/<method call>`

I am looking for different POST requests.

Comment: welcome to the community. If let's say Swagger/OpenAPI is not secured and publicly accessible you could see the whole API or what's documented. Tools like `Nikto` could give you extra information as well. The methods themselves usually get bruteforced though as far as I know..

Answer (score 1):

Any URL can be called with **any** HTTP method. How the server responds is a different story, and there's no way to know that based on the URL only.

You need to have some better description than URLs only (e.g. [openapi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenAPI_Specification)) in order to answer the "does this URL accept POST requests?" question.